# Confusion about Theorem 5.5 in Struwe's book

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

In Struwe's book, the section on Ekeland's variational principal, i.e, Thm. 5.1 has that $(M, d)$  is a metric space in its hypothesis. In Thm. 5.5, he uses Thm. 5.1 with
\begin{equation}
M\equiv u_0+H^{1, 1}_0(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^N)
\end{equation}and
\begin{equation}
d(w, v)\equiv \|Dw-Dv\|_{L^1(\Omega)}.
\end{equation} Here $u_0$ is any element in $H^{1, s}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $s\in (1, \infty)$.

If $u_0$ does not have zero trace, then why is $u_0+H_0^{1, 1}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^N)$ a metric space with respect to the metric $d$? Doesn't $0$ have to belong to $M$ for $M$ to be a metric space?

Comment: In answer to your last question: no. A metric space is any set equipped with a metric. In particular, it doesn't even have to have an additive structure defined on it.

Comment: @Rhys Steele Right, well that clears it up then. Thanks.